# the z.raio in a result of the post-hoc test using "emmeans"

Tags: r, emmeans

I'm working on creating the models using the glmer function and using the emmeans package to compare the effects of different fixed factors on participants' responses.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAWhu.png)
However, I'm having a trouble interpreting the result, especially the z.ratio.  I noticed that the z.ratio in the result is over 10, and I'm not sure if it's correct because a value of "10" seems quite large for the z.ratio, which typically indicates the statistical significance of a difference.
I would appreciate guidance on how to interpret this z.ratio accurately.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWDc3.png)

I've reviewed the manual for the emmeans package ("emmeans.pdf"), but I couldn't find specific definition for the z.ratio.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure to add code/logs as text and formatted with the coding option. Not as a picture! This can help other users help you out faster and easier

Comment: Each z ratio is the estimated contrast divided by its standard error. That is the meaning of a z ratio in many, many contexts, not just in **emmeans**.  You are right that a z of 10 is quite significant, as also is indicated by its associated very small P value. Refer to an intro statistics textboo for more material on z ratios and P values.